# Ansible azure credentials permission denied

Tags: azure, ansible, ansible-inventory

I am trying to get started with Ansible for Azure. Somehow, I am not able to setup the credentials properly.

I have a single app. a single subscription. So there is no way to mix up secrets, client_id, tenant_id, subscription_id. The application is also given the permissions: 
user_impersonation and User.Read. And I setup everything as admin.

I am trying to run a simple playbook to create a group. Yet I keep getting this error message:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": 
       "Error checking for existence of name rg-cs-ansible - 403 Client Error: 
        Forbidden for url: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/81616dde
        -4cf4-43b8-b29f-XXXXXXXXX/resourcegroups/rg-cs-ansible?api-version=2017-05-10"}
```

The playbook is following:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Create resource group
      azure_rm_resourcegroup:
         name: rg-cs-ansible
         location: eastus
      register: rg
    - debug:
        var: rg
```

What am I missing in this picture?

Comment: Did you give the app Azure RBAC access? You can do that through the Access control (IAM) tab in a sub/resource group/resource.

Comment: @junnas. I read in this article that I need to setup IAM stuff:https://medium.com/@pavithra_38952/building-infrastructure-with-microsoft-azure-and-ansible-e5245e5b33a8. But when  I go to Access control(IAM), I do not see the app as actor I can assign the access to. Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. My issue was that to assign IAM, I have to type in the name. I was expecting Azure to provide a dropdown where I can select them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the app Azure RBAC access.
You can do that through the Access control (IAM) tab in a sub/resource group/resource.
Start typing the app name to the box where you select the user/group/app, and it should be listed.
Then you can choose which role to give.